# Generating Print function for LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

The code that I wrote keeps seg-faulting.

```
void CodeGen::visit(const Print* stmt){
    Value* expr_value = stmt->get_val()->accept(this);
    Function* print_call = llvm_module->getFunction("print");
    if(!print_call){
        FunctionType* func_type = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(llvm_context), 0, false);
        print_call = Function::Create(func_type, Function::ExternalLinkage, "print", llvm_module);
    }
    
    
    ir_builder.CreateCall(print_call, {expr_value});
}
```

I did some "std::cout"ing and it appears to be at getFunction("print"), but even when i try to create a new function, it also segmentation faults.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, although I've never actually dealt with using LLVM IR before. I'm using the llvm doxygen documentation for this.

Comment: The generic answer here is to call the module verifier a little earlier and act on whatever it says. The verifier wants about most problems that later cause crashes.